# ffmpeg - stretched pixel issue

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rembg

**Context**

I'm converting a PNG sequence into a video using FFMPEG. The images are semi-transparent portraits where the background has been removed digitally.

**Issue**

The edge pixels of the subject are stretched all the way to the frame border, creating a fully opaque video.

**Cause Analysis**

The process worked fine in the previous workflow using rembg from command line however, since I started using rembg via python script using alpha_matting to obtain higher quality results, the resulting video has these issues.

The issue is present in both webm format (target) and mp4 (used for testing).

**Command Used**

Command used for webm is:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 64 -framerate 30 -i <png sequence location> -c:v libvpx -b:v 0 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 -c:a libvorbis <png output>
```

**Throubleshooting Steps Taken**

1. *PNG Visual inspection* The PNG images have a fully transparent background as desired.
2. *PNG Alpha Measurement* I have created a couple of python scripts to look at alpha level in pixels and confirmed that there is no subtle alpha level in the background pixels
3. *Exported MP4 with AE* Using the native AE renderer the resulting MP4/H.265 has a black background, so not showing the stretched pixel issue

**Image of the Issue**

[image: Text]

**Sample PNG Image from sequence**
[image: Text]

**Code Context**

rembg call via API using alpha_matting seems to generate a premultiplied alpha which uses non black pixels for 0 alpha pixels.

```py
remove(input_data, alpha_matting=True, alpha_matting_foreground_threshold=250,
                    alpha_matting_background_threshold=250, alpha_matting_erode_size=12)
```

A test using a rough RGB reset of 0-alpha pixels confirms that the images are being played with their RGB value ignoring Alpha.

```py
def reset_alpha_pixels(img):
    # Open the image file
    # Process each pixel
    data = list(img.getdata())
    new_data = []
    for item in data:
        if item[3] == 0:
            new_data.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
        else:
            new_data.append((item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]))
        # Replace the alpha value but keep the RGB
        

    # Update the image data
    img.putdata(new_data)

    return img
```

**Updates**

- Added python context to make the question more relevant within SO scope.

Comment: It's a video player issue. The video player doesn't support transparency, and ignores the alpha channel (displays the rgb content of the background). When opening the video in Chrome browser, the background is transparent. We may convert the background to white color (or to black color) while keeping transparency for players that support it. I am not going to post an answer, because the question is not a programming question (it could be if you post the Python code that uses rembg, and post a reproducible code sample).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: The question stems from the programmatic use of ffmpeg and the accepted answer provides an approach to male the output more "player compatible" via python. It also involves use of rembg as part of the issue, so in my opinion it would be a useful reference for anyone facing similar issues while developing a transparent video programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the video player.
Most video players doesn't support transparency, and ignores the alpha (transparency) channel.
The video player displays the rgb content of the background even if the background is supposed to be hidden (background pixels are fully according to their alpha value).
Apparently, rembg output background is not filled with solid black or white, but having the stretched effect.

When opening the PNG image, and when video in Chrome browser for example, the background is transparent (RGB values are hidden), and we can't see the "stretched effect".

---

Solving the issue using FFMPEG is challenging.
We better fix the issue in the Python code after applying rembg.

For fixing the issue, me may select a solid background color like (200, 200, 200) gray background, and apply [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) between RGB channels and the background.

- Extract RGB channels:

```python
    foreground_rgb = image_after_rembg[:, :, 0:3]  # Extract RGB channels.
```

- Extract alpha (transparency) channel and convert from range [0, 255] to [0, 1]:

```python
    alpha = image_after_rembg[:, :, 3].astype(np.float32) / 255  # Extract alpha (transparency) channel and convert from range [0, 255] to [0, 1].
    alpha = alpha[..., np.newaxis]  # Add axis - new alpha shape is (1024, 1024, 1). We need it for scaling 3D rgb by 2D alpha channel.
```

- Set background RGB color to light gray color (for example):

```python
    background_rgb = np.full_like(foreground_rgb, (200, 200, 200))  # Set background RGB color to light gray color (for example).
```

- Apply "alpha compositing" of rgb and background_rgb:

```python
    composed_rgb = foreground_rgb.astype(np.float32) * alpha + background_rgb.astype(np.float32) * (1 -alpha)
    composed_rgb = composed_rgb.round().astype(np.uint8)  # Convert to uint8 with rounding.
```

- Add the original alpha channel to composed_rgb:

```python
    composed_rgba = np.dstack((composed_rgb, alpha_ch))
```

---

Complete Python code sample:

```python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#from rembg import remove

#image_file_before_rembg = 'input.png'
image_file_after_rembg = 'frame-00001.png'

# Assume code for removing background looks as follows:
#image_before_rembg = Image.open(image_file_before_rembg)
#image_after_rembg = remove(image_before_rembg)
#image_after_rembg.save(image_file_after_rembg)

image_after_rembg = Image.open(image_file_after_rembg)  # Skip background removing, and read the result from a file.
image_after_rembg = np.array(image_after_rembg)  # Convert PIL to NumPy array.

foreground_rgb = image_after_rembg[:, :, 0:3]  # Extract RGB channels.
alpha_ch = image_after_rembg[:, :, 3]  # Extract alpha (transparency) channel
alpha = alpha_ch.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert alpha from range [0, 255] to [0, 1].
alpha = alpha[..., np.newaxis]  # Add axis - new alpha shape is (1024, 1024, 1). We need it for scaling 3D rgb by 2D alpha channel.

background_rgb = np.full_like(foreground_rgb, (200, 200, 200))  # Set background RGB color to light gray color (for example).

# Apply "alpha compositing" of rgb and background_rgb
composed_rgb = foreground_rgb.astype(np.float32) * alpha + background_rgb.astype(np.float32) * (1 -alpha)

composed_rgb = composed_rgb.round().astype(np.uint8)  # Convert to uint8 with rounding.

composed_rgba = np.dstack((composed_rgb, alpha_ch))  # Add the original alpha channel to composed_rgb


Image.fromarray(composed_rgba).save('new_frame-00001.png')  # Save the RGBA output image to PNG file
```

---

Executing FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5 -i new_frame-00001.png -vf "format=rgba" -c:v libvpx -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm
```

---

When playing with Chrome browser, the background is transparent.

When playing with VLC Player, the background is light gray:

[image]

---

Using FFmpeg CLI, we have to use `alphaextract`, `overlay` and `alphamerge` filters.

Example (5 seconds at 3fps for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 3 -loop 1 -i frame-00001.png -filter_complex "color=white:r=3[bg];[0:v]format=rgba,split=2[va][vb];[vb]alphaextract[alpha];[bg][va]scale2ref[bg0][v0];[bg0][v0]overlay=shortest=1,format=rgb24[rgb];[rgb][alpha]alphamerge" -c:v libvpx -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 -t 5 out.webm`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. You are spot on about the issue being on the player end, not realising that there is such little support for transparency.

Comment: I answered the question because the subject is interesting. We were both downvoted because the question as its is, is not a programming question and considered out of topic for SO site. Can you please add some Python code, and add a python tag, for making the question "in topic"?

Comment: `overlay=shortest=1,format=rgb24` --> the overlay will generate its output as yuv420p and then the auto-inserted scale converts to rgb24. Add `format=auto` to the overlay to avoid the roundtrip.

Comment: @Rotem thanks, I thought ffmpeg command line syntax was in scope with SO, but I now get why this was being downvoted. I added some python context, but I appreciate this question is a bit out of scope here.